# How do I apply the the same EnvelopeTabs on multiple Documents

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to create an EnvelopeTab for a Signer and when it comes to the DocumentId of the Tab I can only specify 1 ID at a time. If I tried to specify more than one documentId e.g.  `"documentId": "1,2"` then there will be an error saying "1,2" is not recognized.

What if I want to apply this same tab on more than 1 document? How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to mark a tab's location is to use "[AutoPlace](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience)" which looks for `Anchor Text`. When you create an AutoPlace tab via the API, one or more tabs will be created since the Anchor Text is searched for in **all** of your envelope's documents.

Example in Node.JS:

```
// Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
// We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
//
// The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
// documents for matching anchor strings. So the
// signHere2 tab will be used in both document 2 and 3 since they
// use the same anchor string for their "signer 1" tabs.
let signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '**signature_1**',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'})
, signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '/sn1/',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'})
;
```